# В чем разница между API и REST API?

Tags: api, rest, терминология

На собеседовании мне задали вопрос "В чем разница между API и REST API?". 
Может кто нибудь пояснить?

Comment: Чтобы API можно было считать RESTful нужно придерживаться ряда рекомендаций по архитектуре. Неплохая статья для понимания: https://habrahabr.ru/post/265845/

Answer (score 9):

API - это общий термин, который означает "программный интерфейс приложения".
Rest API - это конкретный API, под названием REST, описывающий протокол взаимодействия с веб-сервисом.